# .net core 1.1 compatibility with FoxIDs SAML 2

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, foxids

I have a .net application which is using very old version of .net which is  .net core 1.1. We have a requirement to integrate SAML2 identity provider in our organization. We can't upgrade this application to newer .net version for some reasons.

I have read your github documentation where it is mentioned to use minimum .net core 3.1.
My Question is that
Is there any kind of possibility or hack where I can use ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 package in my application which is having older .net version.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use .NET Core 1.1 without also using the full .NET Framework. Which is a bad idea and probably not possible either.

I think the best solution is to use a broker to transfer from [SAML 2.0 to OpenID Connect](https://www.foxids.com/docs/up-party-saml-2.0). Then you need to implement OpenID Connect in your applications, which is possible in .NET Core 1.1.